# No class error even though the .class files are present

Tags: java, java-server

Getting a `Error: Could not find or load main class KnockKnockServer`, when running the below code using `java KnockKnockServer 4444`, even though the class file *KnockKnockServer.class* is present in the directory.

I was following [this link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html) to about learn the server-client working.

```
 import java.net.*;
 import java.io.*;

public class KnockKnockServer {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Could not listen on port: 4444.");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    Socket clientSocket = null;
    try {
        clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Accept failed.");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(
            clientSocket.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine, outputLine;
    KnockKnockProtocol kkp = new KnockKnockProtocol();

    outputLine = kkp.processInput(null);
    out.println(outputLine);

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
         outputLine = kkp.processInput(inputLine);
         out.println(outputLine);
         if (outputLine.equals("Bye."))
            break;
    }
    out.close();
    in.close();
    clientSocket.close();
    serverSocket.close();
}
}
```

Comment: Have you compiled the code?

Comment: yes, the code is compiled

Comment: Are you running on the dir where class file exists?

Comment: yes the directory is same where the .java file exist

Comment: Well, the error clearly says your class file doesn't exist. You need to find the .class file and then run it.

Comment: True, but as already mentioned the respective .class file is present in the same directory, still the error comes up strangely.

Comment: Try "java -cp . KnockKnockServer 4444"

Comment: @RobertKock Thanks a lot, that worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't pass the classpath on the commandline, it considers the CLASSPATH environment variable. And only if that one is not set either, it considers the default one, being "."

Therefore, either unset the `CLASSPATH` environment variable or pass `-cp .` on the command line.